# Keyboard Shortcut for opening Most Visited Pages in Google Chrome on WIndows

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know if there is a keyboard shortcut for opening up your most visited pages on the Chrome New Tab page?

For example I would like to be able to press a combination of keys to open a weather site I visit frequently instead of going to the new tab page and then clicking on the thumbnail.

Comment: You can use an external program like AutoHotKey to set up a hotkey to open the webpage. If your default browser is Chrome, it will make a new tab in it and go to the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the a Chrome Extension [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf).

Taken from it's description:

```
Customize shortcut keys; Assign any Javascript code or browser actions to any key strokes.

You can change the browser default shortcut keys, and assign any bookmarklets or Javascript action to your hotkeys. It works as Keyconfig on Firefox.
Example actions:
 - Tabs: "Left Tab", "Upper directory", "Close right tabs", "Open your favorite page",...
 - Page: "Scroll up/down", "Insert your signature",...
 - Special: "Screen Capture"
 - Custom: Execute any Bookmarklets or Javascript code!
You can also import or export your settings so you can share it with others.
```